# eBot Setup Fontend and Backend

Tags: symfony, frontend, backend

I was trying to setup ebot for the one that don't know is a programs that allows you to manage multiple servers and games in csgo but Im stuck when trying to install it. Could some one please help I have tried to follow the guide but cant get it to work. I get an error saying ***"# You can find more information about this file on the symfony website: # http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/11-App # default values all:"***

Where is the website with the install guide: http://www.esport-tools.net/ebot/install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the guide at:

http://www.esport-tools.net/ebot/install

Follow all the steps and should work.